# Adding a child entity to parent entityset

Tags: linq-to-sql

Wondering if there is a good way(generic method which is) that can dynamically add child entity to appropriate entity set of a parent. Right now I have to do something like this, and it's not very elegant:

```
 public int AppendChild<T>(PATIENT patient, T child)
    where T : EntityBase

  switch (typeof(T).Name)
  {               
     case "EYE_EXAM":
          patient.EYE_EXAMS.Add((EYE_EXAM)child);
          break;

     case "LEGS_EXAM":
          patient.LEGS_EXAMS.Add(LEGS_EXAM)child);
          break;

     //etc, a very long list of possible types goes here

  }
```

Is there better way to do this? Thanks for answers

Comment: Hi, if you found my answer helpful, it would've great if you could mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!  If not, let me know how I can improve it and I'd be glad to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CreateChildIfNull<T>()
{
    var child = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    Entity.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(T).Name).SetValue(patient, child , null);
}
```

or

```
    public void CreateChildIfNull(LambdaExpression Child)
    {
        Type ChildType = Child.Body.Type;
        var myvar = Activator.CreateInstance(ChildType);
        Entity.GetType().GetProperty(ChildType.Name).SetValue(Entity, myvar, null);
    }
```